# How ZenTest works in detecting file save?

Tags: ruby, zentest

I read some source code of ZenTest but didn't find where it is implemented.

Could you give me give some clue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like its in `autotest.rb` the method is called `find_files_to_test`, the algorithm is pretty basic, every second it checks the dates on all the files that affect testing and then, using some dependency analysis on the changed files, it decides which tests to run.

In Windows this would be significantly faster if it used a file system watcher.

The sleep time is defined initialize `self.sleep = 1` and invoked from `wait_for_changes`

```
Kernel.sleep self.sleep until find_files_to_test
```